# Mono dll.config search path

Tags: c#, mono, pinvoke, opentk

Imagine a library that requires a dll.config file for cross-platform p/invokes with Mono. Is it possible to either:

1. Embed the dll.config as a resource and somehow pass it to Mono at runtime?
2. Place this dll.config into some other, *writable* location on disk? (i.e. not in the same folder as the actual dll file)

Either approach would simplify deployment for my users. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the mono-config man page, the runtime will also load a config file from ~/.mono/assemblies/ASSEMBLY/ASSEMBLY.EXT.config (that is in the user's home directory).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. First time I've heard of the mono-config manpage, too.

Comment: Just note that the documentation is wrong: the config file must be named ASSEMBLY.config **not** ASSEMBLY.EXT.config!